# How do I completely avoid globals in my Express backend?

Tags: javascript, express, refactoring

[image]

This is the heart of my backend. fobjCreator() returns a closure which has access to all my methods which the frontend interacts with. This allowed me to reduce globals to one but seems very monolithy and unwieldy. Any suggestions on refactoring?

Comment: Why do you insist on having no globals? What's wrong with that?

Comment: I don't really mind globals. However, this monolithic structure seems very unwieldy and will only grow as I add more features.

Comment: Then you should think about how to extend it using modules, plugins.